# How to use Google Colaboratory server as python interpreter in Python IDE?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, spyder, google-colaboratory

Google Colaboratory currently by default provides Jupyter notebook like interface for code development. But I feel that code development on this interface without advanced IDE features is constraining.

If I can use Google Colaboratory as a remote python console server for code development in IDE like Spyder or Pycharm it will be great. How do I do this?

Comment: I've requested it here for PyCharm: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/2175305

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's possible but you can use the PyCharm IDE supports this type of interface and features. Plus, it provides many more features. Please check out https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-ipython-notebook-with-product.html.

Answer (score 1):

Google Collaboratory cannot be used as a remote python console.
Check out this [FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) which states clearly that it is just a Jupyter notebook environment.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're asking about using Google Colaboratory as a remote Python console server for code development in IDE. You can achieve this using a combination of [ColabCode](https://github.com/abhishekkrthakur/colabcode) and [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). Here are the steps:

1. **Create [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) Account and Get Token:**
   Start by creating an Ngrok account and obtaining an authentication token. This token will be used to authenticate Ngrok.
2. **Set Up the Colab Notebook:**
   In a new [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) notebook, run the following code to install the required package and set up ColabCode:

   ```py
   !pip install colabcode

   from colabcode import ColabCode
   !ngrok authtoken YOUR_NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN

   ColabCode(port=9999)
   ```

   Replace **`YOUR_NGROK_AUTH_TOKEN`** with the token you obtained from your [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) account.
3. **Selecting Runtime Type:**
   Make sure to adjust the runtime type according to your requirements (GPU or TPU) by going to the "Runtime" menu and selecting "Change runtime type." before run the above code.
4. **Accessing the Remote IDE:**
   After running the code, you'll see an Ngrok-generated link in the output. Clicking this link will open a browser-based IDE (Visual Studio Code in your case) with access to the resources of your Colab instance.
   [image]
5. **Maintain the Connection:**
   Remember not to close the Colab notebook while you are actively using the remote IDE. Closing the notebook will also terminate the connection to the remote IDE.

Using this setup, you can effectively use Google Colaboratory as a remote Python console server for code development in an IDE-like environment. Just make sure to follow all the steps and keep the Colab notebook running to retain your connection to the remote IDE.